# rails default selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have following code for radio options in loop.

```
 <% @this.each do |p| %>
 <div class="radio_button_with_text">
         <%=radio_button  "this" ,"name",p.name ,:onclick=>"save_package(#{p.id})"%>

        <p class="radioText"><%= p.name %></p>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

I wish to have the first radio option default selected. How can I do this?

```
:checked => this.first
```

is not wokring  for me.

Comment: You need to ensure that the value of the first radio option equals the value of your radio button method.  This can be done in the view, but perhaps should be done in the controller before invoking the view.  See documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/radio_button).

Comment: So I tried to get it with js.    `$('input:radio:first-child').attr('checked',true);`   but this isn't selecting the 1st radio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Example:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <div class="radio_button_with_text">
     <%=radio_button_tag  product.name ,:id, @products.first == product, class: "save_package", "data-id" => product.id %>
     <p class="radioText"><%= product.name %></p>
   </div>
<% end %>

$(document).on('click', '.save_package', function(e) {
  save_package(this.attr("data-id"));
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks